# OpenCV : How do I find the minimum element along a specific dimension?

Tags: opencv

I'm a new user to OpenCV. I'm using version 2.3.2 (from the SVN repository). 
I have a specific 3-dimensional `cv::Mat` structure which is 288 x 384 x 10. This represents a 288 x 384 image and the other 10 channels represent a disparity value. I want to find the minimum element and its location. There is a `minMaxElem` function in OpenCV with it doesn't work with multi-dimensional arrays. Any idea how I can use the channel splitting functions in OpenCV to perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use minMaxIdx function to find minimum/maximum on multidimensional array:

```
void minMaxIdx(InputArray src, double* minVal, double* maxVal,
                      int* minIdx=0, int* maxIdx=0, InputArray mask=noArray());
```

Non-zero `minIdx` and `maxIdx` should point to the arrays having enough length to store indexes for all dimensions (3 for 3-dimensional Mat).
`minVal` and `maxVal` are used to return single minimum/maximum value. They can be 0 if you don't need the values.

Comment: Thanks a lot... that works very well. I want to extend it a litte now... I want to loop over every i,j in the matrix and I want to take the min only along the 3rd dimension... is there anything in openCV that can help me do this?

Comment: @Mustafa You should be able to set a ROI for your i and j with `Mat operator()( const Range* ranges ) const;` and next find the min with `minMaxIdx`.